# Combining two Javascript and jQuery scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two seperate Javascript/jQuery scripts which I would like to combine. One is a tabbed search box script which determines the destination of the form when it is submitted. The other is a simple Javascript search script.

I want to combine the two scripts so that the tabbed script determines the place to pull content from in the search script. I hope people can understand what I am trying to describe.

My Javascript search script is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#query").keyup(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode==13){
            var query=$(this).val();
            var yt_url='search.php?q='+query;
            window.location.hash='search/'+query+'/';
            $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url:yt_url,
                dataType:"html",
                success:function(results){
                   $('#results').html(results);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

My tabbed search script is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    Tabs.types.init('search');
    Tabs.search.init();
});

var Tabs = {
    search: {
        init: function () {
            jQuery(Tabs.element.form).bind('submit', function (evt) {
                evt.preventDefault();
                Tabs.search.submit();
            });
        },
        submit: function () {
                var type = Tabs.types.selected;
                var url = type;
                window.location.href = url;
        },
    },
    types: {
        init: function (selected) {
            Tabs.types.selected = selected;
            jQuery('.' + Tabs.types.selected).addClass('selected');
            jQuery(Tabs.element.types).bind('click', function () {
                Tabs.types.click(jQuery(this));
            });
        },
        click: function (obj) {
            jQuery(Tabs.element.types).each(function () {
                if (jQuery(this).hasClass('selected')) {
                    jQuery(this).removeClass('selected');
                }
            });
            if (obj.hasClass('web')) Tabs.types.selected = 'search';
            if (obj.hasClass('images')) Tabs.types.selected = 'images';
            if (obj.hasClass('videos')) Tabs.types.selected = 'videos';
            if (obj.hasClass('news')) Tabs.types.selected = 'news';
            if (obj.hasClass('social')) Tabs.types.selected = 'social';
            obj.addClass('selected');
        }
    },
    element: {
        types: '.type',
        form: '#search',
    },
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the selected tab from `Tabs.types.selected` and know it on your query. For example

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#query").keyup(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode==13){
            var query=$(this).val();
            var yt_url='search.php?tab=' + Tabs.types.selected + '&q=' + encodeURIComponent(query);
            window.location.hash='search/'+query+'/';
            $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url:yt_url,
                dataType:"html",
                success:function(results){
                   $('#results').html(results);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I suggest to encode your query with `encodeURIComponent`, or else if your user type & and ? and other symbols, then never reach your page as parametres.

Also place the `var Tabs = { search: { ..etc` before this code so you are sure that the Tabs are found.

Comment: @callum this is a different issue. Do you wish to work both search, or only one of them ? The line that do that is here Tabs.search.submit();