# Unable to get correct posted data from AJAX call in asp.net handler

Tags: asp.net, jquery, httphandler

I am calling a handler through a AJAX call . 
**code**

```
var PostData = {"MyName": myName };
$_.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            async: true,                                
            url: 'SomeGenericHandler.ashx',                                
            data: JSON.stringify(PostData),
            success: function (msg)
            {
                var ObjJson = eval(msg);        
            },
            error: function (msg)
            {   
            }
        });
```

Inside ProcessRequest ,these values i am getting :

```
context.Request.Form.Count = 1 
context.Request.Form[0] = "{'MyName':'dave'}"
context.Request.Form["MyName"] = null
```

How can get the posted data as :
context.Request.Form["MyName"] = "dave"

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send the data in the format of the post as:

```
$_.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            async: true,                                
            url: 'SomeGenericHandler.ashx',                                
            data: 'MyName=dave&MoreData=SecondName',
            success: function (msg)
            {
                var ObjJson = eval(msg);        
            },
            error: function (msg)
            {   
            }
        });
```

Also take a look at the `encodeURIComponent`, you may need to encode the parameters :

[Combining two Javascript and jQuery scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477106/combining-two-javascript-and-jquery-scripts/6477174#6477174)

Comment: @Sh_Invi `Help me out!!` you mean this helps you out ? or need more help ? JSON is very common, you just need to decode it on code behind.